# Access class member within callback when inside ES6 class statement

Tags: javascript, es6-class

**Important** I'm using the ES6 class statement. Answers about "classes" defined with a function don't apply because something like `var this = that` are not allowed in a class statement. The answers I've seen on this don't work. No variables outside the callback are visible.

```
WebPageReader.Storage = class {
  constructor(object) {
    this.Object = object;
    var self = this; // self is out of scope when constructor completes
  }

  // var self = this; // not allowed here

  Load() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get('somesetting',
      function (setting) {
        console.log(this.Object); // I need to do something with this.Object defined at the class level, but this points to something besides my class.
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `var that = this;` is pretty much allowed, just put it in the first line of `Load` function body or use arrow function as a callback handler.

Comment: @zerkms, I'll try it, but I don't think it's going to work b/c other variables in load aren't visible. Thanks!

Comment: @zerkms using an arrow function is a great solution.  You should re-post as an answer.  `chrome.storage.sync.get('somesetting', setting => console.log(this.Object));`

Comment: @zerkms, except, it did work! thanks! (things that make you go hmmm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow either of the two:

```
  Load() {
    const that = this;

    chrome.storage.sync.get('somesetting',
      function (setting) {
        console.log(that.Object);
      }
    );
  }
```

or

```
  Load() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get('somesetting',
      setting => {
        console.log(this.Object);
      }
    );
  }
```

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions